# A (different) helper for `std::unique_ptr`

Tags: c++, c++14, smart-pointers

I see that there is only one non-member utility helper associated with `std::unique_ptr`, and it invokes `new`.  What about a utility for wrapping an existing raw pointer without having to explicitly name the type?

In particular, suppose there is legacy code or external library that has something like this:

```
C* foo();  // caller is responsible for deleting
```

That is, some function that *ought* to be written as returning a `unique_ptr<C>`, but isn't, and the caller is not in a position to change it.

I think the proper way to use this function is with:

```
unique_ptr<C> up (foo());
```

but that requires naming the type, rather than using `auto`.  It begs the question as to why there's not a helper function that would use template argument deduction and write something like:

```
auto up= capture_unique(foo());
```

Ideally, even provide for the `=` syntax in declaring the variable, as well as figuring out the type by itself.

It's such a natural way to write it that I can't imagine that I'm the first to think of it.  Is there some hidden peril that makes it impossible to write this in a general enough case?  Or, what reason is it not provided along with `make_unique` and the `unique_ptr` template as part of the standard?

Comment: Is there more to it than just `template<typename T> auto capture_unique(T* ptr) noexcept { return std::unique_ptr<T>{ptr}; }`? Anyway, I imagine lack of knowledge regarding the deleter makes this mostly useless in real code.

Comment: deleter:  I think most code uses plain operator delete for pointers it returns.  Having to use specific calls for deleting is even worse, and I'd do a one-time overloading of that pointer type or wrap the legacy function if it's really odd.  IAC, it should be useful in the same cases where you *could* use a unique_ptr with explicitly naming the type.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest code that satisfies the requirement you describe would be;

```
template<typename T>
auto capture_unique(T* ptr)
{
  return std::unique_ptr<T>{ptr};
}
```

And that would work nicely with the sample code;

```
auto up = capture_unique(foo());
```

There is essentially little difference between the `capture_unique` and just using the `unique_ptr` constructor directly, other than as you say, retyping the type `C`.

```
auto up = std::unique_ptr<C>{foo()};
```

For generic code you could look to use `decltype` and `declval` etc. A generalised use case probably does not exist.

In the same problem exists for `std::shared_ptr` where there is again no "capture" type helper method, again, creating one is simple enough. The difference between the `shared_ptr` case and the `unique_ptr` is that the deleter is part of the type with `unique_ptr` and not with `shared_ptr`.

> Is there some hidden peril that makes it impossible to write this in a general enough case?

No hidden peril, just some unanswered general questions on what types to use. But easy enough to create, as above.

> Or, what reason is it not provided along with `make_unique` and the `unique_ptr` template as part of the standard?

It is possible that the deleter being part of the type is a good reason to not create a utility capture method (and thus in turn it is not mirrored for `shared_ptr`). The `capture_unique` would not be able to provide a better syntax if the deleter was the default `delete` - it may well be more cumbersome.

Note: both the "factory" methods, `make_unique` and `make_shared` use the `new` operator and marry that with the default `delete` deleter.